# XML parser plugin

Tags: plugins

I have an XML data source that updates daily. Is there a plugin that will allow me to create a query and update it daily with the least programming possible and display the data on a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML as in generic XML? I mostly mess with RSS (for which WordPress has SimplePie bundled).

Maybe [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) (PHP 5+, not WP specific) will do?

Also quick repository search found this: [Advanced XML Reader](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-xml-reader/)

Comment: Thanks, I've worked out a solution that uses SimpleXML and very little coding ;-)